# Angular2 - How to put TextBox in *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to put a textbox in `*ngFor` Like

```
<tr *ngFor="let abc in _Apple">    
  <td>{{abc.Name}}</td>
  <td> <input matInput  name="UnitofPrice" [(ngModel)] = "UnitofPrice">
</td>
<td>{{UnitofPrice}}</td>
```

If I enter anything in `UnitofPrice` it reflects to all.
How can i remove it?

Comment: It is because you are binding all the input filed with the same `model` key i.e., `UnitofPrice`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your NG model Unique with index of the ngFor:
See Example:

```
<tr *ngFor="let abc in _Apple; let i = index;">

<td>{{abc.Name}}</td>
<td> <input matInput  name="UnitofPrice" [(ngModel)]="abc[i]">
</td>
<td>{{UnitofPrice}}</td>
```

in you button or Submit function pass this as Parameter like:

```
<button (click)="yourFunc(abc[i])">submit</button>
```

Comment: [(ngModel)]="abc[i]"   how can bind in {{}}

Comment: Thank u soo muych\